# Get table as two parts in django

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I have a question about data filtering. For example we have a model Shop with name, which is FK to to model Names (name, active). What if I need to filter Shop names which are active, and not active in 1 view? Using 2 two queries is an only option? If not, can someone please show effective way to this? Question is, can I get table as two parts, divided by simple condition without running two queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by your description, you have a model arrangement like this, Right?

```
class Name(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    active = models.CharField()

class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Name)
```

Then you can do something like this :

```
active_list = []
inactive_list = []
shop_list = Shop.objects.all()

for shop in shop_list :
    if shop.name.active :
        #Do something
        active_list.append(shop)

    else :
        #Do something else
        inactive_list.append(shop)

print active_list
print inactive_list
```

At the end of this loop, you will have all the shops based on active or inactive fields.

**EDIT:**

As mentioned in comments, if Names objects needs to be selected based on active,inactive You can use this :

```
active_list = []
inactive_list = []
name_list = Names.objects.all()

for names in name_list :
    if names.active == True :
        #Do something
        active_list.append(names)
    else :
        #Do something else
        inactive_list.append(names)
print active_list
print inactive_list
```

Comment: Yes, you catch it well. Thanks, I know that I can make it with simple loop. But I thought about how db filter table. If db decides to remove raw from result, why it be can returned as result addition?

Comment: @wowbrowsersearch What else do you need from it?? What are the values of active field in Name model??

Comment: I'm just asking about this:
`active, non_active = Names.objects.filter(shop=shop, active=True, bad_results=True)`

Comment: @wowbrowsersearch what is bad_results field.It's not mentioned in the question.

Comment: @wowbrowsersearch where is this code from ?? Are you using any tutorials??

Comment: @wowbrowsersearch This is not correct.You can not use **active, non_active = Names.objects.filter(shop=shop, active=True, bad_results=True)** like this.

Comment: Nope, it's not from any tutorial, but from my head. Imagine set of Names as A set. And set of active names as B set. Why I cann't get B set and A - B set in 1 query? Why I need to filter the remainig part of table, if I already have filtered part of it?

Comment: @wowbrowsersearch Now I understood your point. If you look closely, with my logic you are not filtering the remaining part, the calculation is done only one time in if condition. When the if condition is not satisfied then data is saved automatically into another list.No double calculations.

Comment: Yes, your code is correct. But database already did it when filter active names, why I cann't get it from db directly?